# For... Next loop in VBA exceeds limit

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I am using a `For... Next` loop to populate an array as below

```
ReDim array(1 to 100, 1 to 100)

For i = 1 to 100

Next i
```

But the `i` counter seems to always go to 101 instead of stopping at 100. Thus this creates a 101th element in my array, which is giving me error "Subscript out of range". Anybody have an idea how to resolve?

Comment: If you use i to access an array element after the end of the loop, i will be 101 and you will get this error. The last i value is 101, it is just that the loop code is not executed for i = 101.Does this happen?

Comment: @loannis yes that is exactly what happened.

Comment: What is your next line of code after your For loop that you state is throwing the error. Also how are you dimensioning your array. Please add to your question.

Comment: @MarkHall amended my query. i am trying to use the array in subsequent code

Comment: Try   For i = 1 to UBound(yourArrayName) -1 .....

Comment: Actually posting a fuller version of your code could help. Right now the answers are all based on guesswork of what this array - the subject of so much speculation - is, where it's declared, whether it's being redimensioned within or outside the loop, where it's being modified, etc. Tks.

Comment: This question is quite surreal. You are  trying to access (and you are not creating as you say) an element (101) that does not exist. What should we try to resolve? Just don't access it :) set i to any number between 1 and 100 and access your array as MyArray(i,8) or MyArrsy(5,i) or MyArray(i,i). If you want i=100 after the end of the loop, just write i=100 after the end of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Next i` step is equivalent of writing

```
i = i + Step    'Step is an optional parameter which defaults to 1 for VBA For loops
Goto Loop_Start
```

Hence, when you finish the loop, the counter will always be set to 1 (or more depending on `Step` size) greater than the maximum loop value which produces a `True` condition.

You can try this little code to test it yourself.

```
Sub TestCLoop()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 100
    Next i

    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

You will get the result as ...

[image: Output of the empty loop, as you see, <code>i = i + 1</code>]

If you plan to use the 'last value' after the loop is done, the way to go about is

```
Sub TestCLoop()
    Dim i As Long, MaxValue as Long
    MaxValue = 100

    For i = 1 To MaxValue
         ' Do something
    Next i

    i = MaxValue

    'Use i now
End Sub
```

This should solve the problem if a lot of code using `i` is already written. IMHO, you shouldn't use increment variables after they are used in the incremental loop process as it leads to errors such as what you just experienced (unless you really know what you're doing, e.g. knowing what `Next i` does, etc.).

Moreover, a good design practice would be to run your loops not to a hardcoded maximum value but to a variable which holds this value or some constant declared in a very visible place in the program. That makes modification of the code easier and it's more likely to stay bug free.

Comment: Appreciate the support, tks. Initially I thought the solution is obvious once the possibly obscure behavior of `Next` is described, but you're right, for the sake of completeness, I put in the solution to the problem as well as 2+ cents :)

Comment: Excellent advice and example - understanding what code does is the foundation that people tend to neglect.

Comment: @hnk I added i = MaxValue after the for-next loop and it work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Wonderful. Also do note the points I made about using increment counters outside the loops. Might be useful in other code.

Answer (score 1):

The above for loop is just like

```
i = 0
While i < 101
    ' DoSomething
    array(i)
    i = i + 1
End While
```

After the last iteration `i = 101` and the condition is false, hence you see the value "exceeds" what you expected.

But the real cause is that **the index of an array sized N *often* goes from 0 to N-1**, so you should edit your for loop to run from 0 to 99

## Edit:

After the edit it's clear to see that the OP is using 1-indexed array. That means the below code **should work fine without any out-of-range error**

```
For i = 1 to 100
    array(i) ' Do something with it
Next i
```

unless the OP is accessing `array(i + 1)` or higher in the loop. Unfortunately we'll never know

Comment: Yes, you tell me I was wrong in the fact that arrays start at `ZERO`, then in your example you show the count starting at `ZERO`. According to you it should be `ONE` - practice what you preach.

Comment: Hey did you read my answer? I said that it's **often** starts from 0 and you said that it's 0. And it's not a reason downvoting unless it's bad or wrong in some aspects

Comment: Your own answer is wrong according to you. My original answer was `Arrays start at zero...`, you replied `Wrong. VB supports arrays started at 1.` - So downvote stays.

Comment: Don't you understand English? That means arrays in VB can start at 1, not always started at 1

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't understand English in the way you attempt to use it, sorry :)

Comment: the OP has edited and clearly he's using an array starting from 1. Fine

Answer (score 0):

In array, the index for the first element is zero, second element is one and so on. The 100th element is 99. So try this

```
 For i = 0 to 99
```

Comment: But I have set the dimension of the array as such ReDim array(1 to 100, 1 to 100). This would mean my array element starts from 1, rather than 0, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to this question, but I just encountered this issue myself. I used

```
For cntr = 1 to Limit
.
...Run Loop Code
    If cntr = Limit Then Exit For
Next cntr
```

in my loop, and the counter does not exceed my limit.